# Count number of rows with distinct column

Tags: mysql, activerecord

I'm trying to count the number of rows with a distinct column with Active Record.

The following SQL works and gives me the correct result:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM attempts WHERE score = 100 AND problem_id = 1
```

But this code throws an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` error:

```
attempts.where(:score => 100).count(:distinct => :user_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
attempts.count('user_id', :conditions => "score = 100", :distinct => true)
```

*more infos: http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html*